# Third-party assembly comes with deps.json. What do I do with that?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, dependencies

Our VS2022, dotNet 6 project will be using a third party assembly, call it TPA, that comes with a deps.json file. What should I do with that file?

I'll be referencing TPA from a class library project, call it project "B".  Another project references B, and builds an executable.  Call this project C.  The build of C produces a deps.json file that details the full dependency tree of the application.   (right?)

Will VS/MsBuild recognize the third-party deps.json file, sitting next to TPA, and incorporate its details into the final deps.json of the exe? Or do I need to do something else to assure that the third-party deps.json is properly represented in the final output?